# Will Anaconda with Python 3.7 work with Python 3.6.5 environment of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, installation, arcgis-pro, python-3, anaconda

I just uninstalled my Anaconda with Python 3.6 and need to reinstall, but the current version is now with Python 3.7.

Will that work for ArcGIS Pro (Python 3.6.5)?

I'll have to copy the ArcGIS Pro env and place it in my new Anaconda env in order to access my `arcpy` and `arcgis` mods. If it is not compatible, I tried looking in the Anaconda archives to find the old 3.6 install for Windows 10/64-bit, but I didn't see the correct one.

Comment: No it's not compatible, though you can use it to create a compatible environment. You don't have to (shouldn't) copy your env, you can clone it or you can create a new one from scratch. I suggest you have a read of the `conda` documentation, particularly about managing environments.  Are you aware the ArcGIS Pro install comes with conda? And you're adding another conda by installing Anaconda.  That's not necessarily an issue. Just make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Luke Yeah, I am aware that Pro comes with comes with Conda. I believe that I need to reinstall Pro as well. My Pandas  keeps throwing that 'Cannot import AbstractMethod' error which is the whole reason I am reinstalling Anaconda, but it is also thwoing the error when I run `import pandas` in my Pro Python console. Once I reinstall it, can I just do something like `>>conda install anaconda 3.65` ?